# Intentionally corrupt WordPress database

Tags: database

I am writing a document on fixing/troubleshooting common WP issues.  I am looking for a way to intentionally corrupt a WP database for testing.  However, I am not sure how to do that.  Is there something I can do from wp db cli or phpmyadmin?  To clarify, I want to be able to run

```
wp db check
```

That returns as non-ok.

Comment: Rename tables, rename columns, insert wrong data types, those are a few that come to mind.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I tried dropping a table, that did nothing.  I suppose I can try renaming a few.

Comment: Not all tables are used by core wordpress to function. Im sure if you mess with wp_options you will crash your site

Comment: corrupt is a very general term, you could corrupt a database in a way that would not be useful for your troubleshooting document, can you be more specific and provide more context? E.g. do you need this so that you can discover a reliable series of recovery steps? Or do you have a set and need test data to confirm? Please update your question with more context around your intentions, as "corrupt" can mean many things, some of which aren't what you had in mind

Comment: @TomJNowell I updated the question to show exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm sure you could make `wp db check` return `false`/bad without corrupting the database though, do you just need the output it gives when the database is broken? If so that's much easier than what you asked.

Comment: @TomJNowell The output is irrelevant, I want to corrupt the database.  I was talking to some other people who were saying to overwrite part of the database file itself, but I was hoping for something easier.

Comment: So you're testing that `wp db check` fixes it? Or are you testing a script? Explaning the background and _why_ is important to get a correct answer that's usable for your use case, but if we do not know your use case then the answers you get may not be usable. E.g if there was a filter that told `wp db check` to return failed, would that be an acceptable answer? What about a database that was corrupted in such a way that it could never occur in reality? Or if it was corrupted in a way that the repair commands aren't able to fix? If you're just writing docs then you don't need a corrupted DB